# Are ^$ and $^ in PHP regex the same?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, anchor, pcre

Why do both of these regexes match successfully?

```
if(preg_match_all('/$^/m',"",$array))
  echo "Match";

if(preg_match_all('/$^\n$/m',"\n",$array))
  echo "Match";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$` and `^` are zero-width meta-characters. Unlike other meta-characters like `.` which match one character at a time (unless used with quantifiers), they do not actually match literal characters. This is why `^$` matches an empty string `""`, even though the regex (sans delimiters) contains two characters while the empty string contains zero.

It doesn't matter that an empty string contains no characters. It still has a starting point and an ending point, and since it's an empty string both are at the same location. Therefore no matter the order or number of `^` and `$` you use, all of their permutations should match the empty string.

---

Your second case is slightly trickier but the same principles apply.

The `m` modifier (`PCRE_MULTILINE`) just tells the PCRE engine to feed in the entire string at one go, regardless of newlines, but the string still comprises "multiple lines". It then looks at `^` and `$` as "the start of a line" and "the end of a line" respectively.

The string `"\n"` is essentially logically split into three parts: `""`, `"\n"` and `""` (because the newline is surrounded by emptiness... sounds poetic).

Then these matches follow:

1. The first empty string is matched by the starting `$^` (as I explain above).
2. The `\n` is matched by the same `\n` in your regex.
3. The second empty string is matched by the last `$`.

And that's how your second case results in a match.

Comment: As an interesting aside, I find this scenario similar to the question of why the empty string is a substring of itself. So this is not a stupid question at all. In fact I've just upvoted it!

Answer (score 3):

No it is not. Actually, the expression `$^` should never match, because `$` symbolizes the end of a string whereas `^` represents the beginning. But as we know, the end cannot come before the beginning of a string :)

`^$` should match an empty string, and only that.

> The  "start of  line"  metacharacter  (^)  matches only at the start of the string, while the "end of line" metacharacter ($) matches only at  the  end  of the string, [...]

From the [PCRE manpages](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt)

Note that, by adding the `PCRE_MULTILINE` modifier, `$` becomes EOL and `^` becomes BOL, it will match (thanks netcoder for pointing that out). Still, I personally wouldn't use it.

Comment: so why '/$^\n$/m','\n' matches

Comment: Probably because it is a bug in your favorite regex engine :) Or maybe it is defined like that. But it does not make sense logically and you should never use it.

Comment: @nEAnnam: That doesn't match anything for me, and shouldn't.

Comment: @x3ro: So it's a PCRE bug then? Because I verified the question code and `$^` **does** match the empty string (but not the comment just above).

Comment: maybe, cuz both means positions, they match at the same positions, cuz ive tried $(space)^ and dont work

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes, I would say so. As I mentioned, maybe this special case is defined somewhere and it actually does something useful, but that would be most suprising and a design flaw, imho.

Comment: @nEAnnam: @x3ro: @BoltClock: No it's not a bug, and yes it should match for, say `foo\n\n`. With the `m` modifier (PCRE_MULTILINE), `$` becomes EOL and `^` becomes BOL. Therefore, it's perfectly normal that it matches. [It's written in the manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). :)

Comment: Actually, I am pretty sure this is not a bug. See my undeleted answer. *Edit:* thanks @netcoder

Comment: @netcoder: Yes, but he hasn't set the multiline modifier. But true.

Comment: @x3ro: In his example, he didn't. In the comment above, he did. So your answer is a little bit untrue. `^$` will match empty strings, unless the `m` modifier is set, it will also match empty lines. So it will match `foo\n\n\nbar` as well. Maybe you should edit your answer. :)

Comment: yes, with the multiline modiefer, but also works without him, try it

Comment: If you're talking about the `m` in `/$^/m` for `""`, well the `m` modifier should have no effect, because `""` doesn't have any newlines to work with in the first place.

Comment: I have no idea why the OP keeps using `'\n'` instead of `"\n"` for the second match even though it doesn't work, but I've edited the question and my answer to cover why `/$^\n$/m` matches `"\n"` which I assume, hopefully correctly, he meant all along.

Answer (score 1):

`Regex.IsMatch ("", "$^")` matches in C#, also.  Since it is an empty string, there is no size.  At index -1, it is both at the end and beginning of the string, simultaneously.  Good question!

Comment: There is a size... it is 0. (Sorry, I couldn't resist ;)

Comment: @BoltClock.  :-)  I should have said, `there is no spoon`.  This example bent my mind like The Matrix!

Answer (score 0):

In regex, `^` matches the start of the string, and `$` matches the end of the string.

Therefore, regex `/^$/` will successfully match a completely empty string (and nothing else).

`/$^/` will not match anything, as logically you can't have the end of the string before the beginning of it.